# Next.js api route throwing error internal server error in nodemailer

Tags: next.js, cpanel, nodemailer

I am using cpanel to host my next js website , and i have this api route that uses nodemailer to send messages, Any time i call the route i get Internal server error , but it works fine on localhost and even vercel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beqzn.png)

here is the api route => /api/mail

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

type Data = {
  message: string;
};

const handler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<Data>) => {
  const message = {
    from: req.body.email,
    to: "enquiries@domain.com.ng",
    subject: "New Customer Setup",
    text: `${req.body.email} ${req.body.firstname} ${req.body.lastname}`,
    html: `
    <p>Name: ${req.body.firstName} ${req.body.lastName}</p>
    <p>Email: ${req.body.email}</p>
    <p>Phone Number: ${req.body.mobileNumber}</p>
    <p>Residential Address: ${req.body.residentialAddress}</p>
    <p>Gender: ${req.body.gender?.value}</p>
    `,
  };

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    secure: true,
    port: 465,
    host: "domain.com.ng",
    auth: {
      user: "enquiries@domain.com.ng",
      pass: "pass",
    },
  });

  try {
    const info = await transporter.sendMail(message);
    console.log(info);
    res.status(200).json({
      message:
        "Thank you for your interest in domain. Our relationship agent will get back to you shortly.",
    });
  } catch (error:any) {
    console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    
    if (error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Failed to connect to the email server." });
    } else if (error.code === "EAUTH") {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Invalid email credentials. Authentication failed." });
    } else {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "An error occurred while sending the email." });
    }
  }
};

export default handler;
```

then the function that calls the route =>

```js
const onSubmit = async (data: FormData) => {
    const res = await fetch('/api/mail', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json , text/plain, */*'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)

    })
    console.log(res, 'response from server')
    if (res.status === 200) {
      const json = await res.json()
      toast.success(json.message)
      reset()
      router.push('/')
    }
  }
```

But whenever i go to the api route like https://domain.com.ng/api/mail , i get **an error occurred while sending the email**

And if i fill in the form to send , i get **internal server error**
I expected it to log status ok and send the message.

So finally  , i have been able to stop getting the internal server error as a result of using async await , but still yet , the recipient is not receiving the mail even though it returns success.

**my server log**

- App 9469 output:     at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketError (/home2/funditco/nodevenv/frontend_test/16/lib/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:194:45)
  App 9469 output:     at SMTPConnection._onError (/home2/funditco/nodevenv/frontend_test/16/lib/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:780:14)
  App 9469 output:     at SMTPConnection. (/home2/funditco/nodevenv/frontend_test/16/lib/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:176:24)
  App 9469 output:     at /home2/funditco/nodevenv/frontend_test/16/lib/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:230:21

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What error do you have in your server logs?

Answer (score 0):

It is working now , so the reason i get internal server error was as a result of hostname , my hosting provider already set up the smtp configuration .
All i did was change the hostname to 'localhost'